# Linux suspend device/driver issue

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, suspend

I have a embedded device with Linux 4.14. My question/issue is a general one while resuming the system from suspend to ram and relates to the /sys FS and the device nodes which are present in device tree. My problem is that the drivers cannot find any device after resume and I assume the device properties from device tree nodes are gone but I don't know why.

As I understand the device tree is parsed while starting the kernel once. E.g. the usb ehci node which is compatible to the generic-ehci driver. Before the suspend I can see this relation here /sys/bus/platform/ee0a0100.usb/uevent.

```
DRIVER=ehci-platform
OF_NAME=usb
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/usb@ee0a0100
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=generic-ehci
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
MODALIAS=of:NusbT<NULL>Cgeneric-ehci
```

After the resume from the suspend these properties are gone and the ehci_platform driver cannot find any proper device.

```
OF_NAME=usb
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/usb@ee0a0100
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=0
MODALIAS=of:NusbT<NULL>
```

Do I have to initialize the devicetree after resume or save it before suspend? Which component can be responsible for destroying the sys fs informations and how I can prevent it?

thanks
Tobias

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1331450/1030912

Comment: thanks for reply but didn't solve the problem. It effects all the drivers and isn't usb related, usb was just an example.
For example I can remove/load ehci_platform driver successfully but it didn't find any matching device after resume. So no usb device were introduced.
If usb.service (and all the kernel drivers) are never loaded before suspend->resume is started I can see same behavior. So I assume it's no driver issue at all, more a Linux configuration or suspend sequence issue.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://askubuntu.com instead.

Comment: I solved the problem and I can describe the problem. I ran into wrong direction and the issue was caused by the bootloader. In the bootloader I patch the devicetree before it's loaded and in case of warm boot the bootloader was patching the devicetree once more. Thus the devicetree structure in memory once parsed by the kernel was destroyed.